# Java Timer doesn t start after midnight

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks

In my code i m trying to write a task which should be triggered every 24 h. The first trigger should be when the timer is scheduled and then every 7 in the morning. I m using

```
java.util.TimerTask
```

I wrote something like this:

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
timer.schedule(task1, today.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(24, TimeUnit.HOURS));
```

It happens that the task is launched every time i  run my application (as expected?)... but after midnight if i run my application the task is not triggered.

Where is the error?

thanks

Comment: "but after midnight" What do you mean, exactly? All times are after midnight.

Comment: What type is `timer`? (I checked if it was a `ScheduledExecutorService`, but nothing matches that signature).

Comment: java.util.TimerTask ... i mean that i tried to run my application at 00.01 ... and the task was not executed. And every night is the same behaviour

Comment: @JoeC See `java.util.Timer`.

Comment: @Alex are you running this at 00:01, and waiting for 6h59m to see if it executes?

Comment: Is the task not triggered at all (not even at 7am) or not immediately on start?

Comment: i was just wondering why if i run the application during the day and after 7...  the task is executed...  and why if i run the application suddenly after midnight the task is not executed. I thinks that the one of lexicore is a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are providing `07:00:00` of the current day (not the next day) as `firstTime`.

So if the time is after 7am, your `firstTime` is in the past. Probably this is why the task is started immediately.

If the time is "after midnight" which is probably before 7am, the `firstTime` is in the future. So you have to wait for 7am for the task to start.

Comment: I changed now the time trigger time to 0... and the task is started. So the yours seems to be the right answers.